# Deformable object using Bullet or Simbody

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does somebody know which parameters should I write in the sdf file (or in general, what should I do) in order to simulate a deformable object in Gazebo? I've already been able to make a rigid simulation using Ode, Bullet or Simbody physics engines (I don't know which physics engine is better for deformable objects), but I still don't know how to, for example, tell gazebo the stiffness of a link.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12089/deformable-object-using-bullet-or-simbody/) by [ROS_GAZEBO_USER](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1326/ros_gazebo_user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo can't simulate deformable objects. The most we can do is add some softness to a surface.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0